# An Italian rebus

Tags: riddle, rebus, language

How is Giovanni doing?

> lunedì
>   martedì
>   mercoledì
>   giovedì
>   sabato
>   domenica

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is that Giovanni

> is not too bright;
>  is about as sharp as a marble;
>  has got a screw loose.

Explanation:

> * The list states the Italian weekday names, except friday=venerdi.
>  * The phrase "a missing friday" is "gli manca qualche venerdi" in Italian.
>  * The meaning of this Italian phrase is a nicer version of "retarded".
>  * See: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/gli-manca-qualche-venerd%C3%AC.2202059/
>  * See: http://dan.hersam.com/lists/not_bright.html

Comment: if the question is how is he going, maybe we can say he is feeling down ? might be the intended answer